# Layout is Orientation =vertical when device rotate it wont work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following layout set to Orientation = vertical. But when I rotate the emulator to Landscape, it show the Layout in Landscape.

I want the Layout be in orientation vertical even the device rotate to Landscape.

How to solve this problem?  Appreciate your help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Put Your Name here :" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditBox"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hey! Click Me" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:orientation="vertical"` means that the children are inserted into the layout vertically. So when you add more views they will stack underneath each other.

Vertical:

[image: vertical]

Horizontal:

[image: horizontal]

This is the layout I used. Try change the orientation on your own and see the effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <View
        android:background="#aabbdd"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <View
        android:background="#341233"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <View
        android:background="#123456"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <View
        android:background="#654321"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <View
        android:background="#550000"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to lock rotation in your Activity, you need to add the following property to your ActivityAttribute:

```
ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
```

So it will look something like:

```
[Activity(Label = "Herp Derp", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class HerpDerpActivity : Activity
{
    // more stuff here
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is working!  I have to import Android.content.PM for the ScreenOrientation.